# information in tcp packages. How to know destination?

Tags: network-programming, network-protocols, tcp

Suppose we have a web browser with several tabs open and we are working with them.
All TCP packets will arrive with destination port 80 but I don't understand how the browser can know, from all the network traffic, which packages are destined for which tab.

What's more, if there are several browsers, I understand that all the packages destined to them come with port 80. How do you know which ones are intended?

Thak you

Answer (score 3):

TCP connections are identified by the following tuple: Source Ip, Destination Ip, Source Port, Destination Port

Each connection that the browser opens might have the same destination ip & port (e.g. www.google.com port 80), but each connection will have a unique source port number.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose we have a web browser with several tabs open and we are working with them. All TCP packets will arrive with destination port 80

No they won't. They will arrive at the browser with *source* port 80, from the server, but each connection will have a different local port number at the client host.

> but I don't understand how the browser can know, from all the network traffic, which packages are destined for which tab.

It doesn't have to know. All it has to do is read from its various connections via their sockets. Demultiplexing to the respective local ports is TCP's job, not the browser's.

> What's more, if there are several browsers, I understand that all the packages destined to them come with port 80.

Wrong again. They come with *source* port 80, and, again, different destination ports.

> How do you know which ones are intended?

Same answer. They don't. TCP does.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
anyway, how is it possible that incoming connections for the browser are received if their ports were not opened in the firewall?

Comment: @Alberto There is no such thing as an 'incoming conection for the browser'. The browser forms *outbound* connections, which are incoming at the *server*. Most everything you have said here has been back to front.

Answer (score 0):

80 port is used, usually, on the server side. Each browser tab is client, not a server, and uses different port numbers. 
Client reads data from this "own local" port, not directly from the server's 80.

Comment: Yes, and socket is opened on port, so it's the same.

Comment: It's not the same. The client doesn't care about the port. All it has is the socket. The Sockets API provides a `recv()` method that reads from a *socket*. Not a port.

Comment: And the claim 'each browser tab is a client' is very far from the truth. Each tab may form multiple connections, which may be pooled and shared across multiple tabs.

Comment: @EJP You are diving too deep into details. I just want to point to the reason of misunderstanding: 80 - is server port, not client.

Comment: All you have to do is change 'port' to 'socket ' in your answer, then it will be correct. I don't know why you're so resistant to being right.